# Is there a Linux capabilities(7) to allow a process to execute pam_authenticate?

Tags: security, pam, capabilities

I am writing a process that needs to periodically authenticate users (i.e. call `pam_authenticate()`). For security purposes I would prefer not to run this process with `root` privilege. I can use `capabilities(7)` for my other security requirements (i.e. it needs to bind to `HTTPS` port, so can use `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE`).

I could start with root privs and drop them temporarily, raising them only when needed to call `pam_authenticate` and then dropping them again. But as long as the ability remains to raise privs this is really only security-by-obscurity, since an attacker who could gain control of the process could raise the privileges.

Is the security restriction due to/driven by the specific `PAM` modules being utilized? Could it be only `pam_unix.so`'s need to read the `shadow` password file that is causing issues?